# Where is documentation for "AndEngine"?

Tags: android, andengine

I want to get AndEngine documentation, where is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a tricky one, because there isn't any. Just search Stack Overflow and the AndEngine forums, answers to most of the problems you may encounter can be found on these two places and there are many users willing to help.

Answer (score 5):

The [AndEngineExamples](https://github.com/nicolasgramlich/AndEngineExamples) are the documentation. They cover pretty much every single thing you can do with AndEngine. When in question a fierce look at the method name and its parameters should give you a very good idea of what a method is going to do.

Answer (score 3):

The sad thing about opensource gameEngines is that they lack proper documentation, whether it is Cocos-2dx  or AndEngine.
But you can go to the blog for you queries or there is a book released in January this year
[AndEngine Cook Book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/184951898X)

And I also find these links about AndEngine which might be useful to you

[Doc for Andengine](http://srcrr.com/android/AndEngine/GLES2/2012.03.27/reference/classes.html)

[Tutorials for Beginners](http://www.andengine.org/forums/tutorials/mimminito-s-tutorial-list-t417.html)

Answer (score 2):

There's a book you can read about Android game development, 'Learning Android Game Programming: A Hands-On Guide to Building Your First Android Game' ISBN-10: 0321769627
The author uses AndEngine for the whole book.

Comment: AndEngine is developing rapidly, so the book will be painfully outdated by now unless the author keeps an updated version on the web. Many things are now done differently in AndEngine, just enough to cause a lot of confusion and utter desperation. It is a much better idea to focus on the up-to-date GLES2 tutorials on the AndEngine forum.

Answer (score 2):

There is also the book: AndEngine for Android Game Development Cookbook by 
Jayme Schroeder, Brian Broyles (ISBN: 184951898X ISBN-13: 9781849518987), which I have been using quite extensively. 
It explains by example how AndEngine works.